# netty NioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, netty

Netty version netty-3.2.4.Final.jar

some time have NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(NioWorker.java:620) ~[netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:592) ~[netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:355) ~[netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280) ~[netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200) ~[netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_24]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_24]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in later releases. You should upgrade..

Comment: Is there a fix bug link?